# Clicking on a specific picture to open a specific video in an iframe

Tags: image, iframe, onclick

I a trying to click on a picture (and depending on picture clicked on) and 
am assigning a specific youtube video to an iframe source. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<img id="image2" 
          onclick= "iframe.bigVideo.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5t7x8KwJ"
          class="crop-img"
          src="images/lastcall.jpg"
          alt="Last Call
         /> 
       </div>

 <iframe name ="bigVideo"
       width="100%" 
       height="100%" 
       src="" 
       frameborder="0" 
       allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17315071/1530987)

Comment: Thanks, but that puts the video in same location as picture. In my case (apologies  if i didn't explain it right ) I have four or five pictures and i want to display the video(s) below them in a specific location using iframe